# How to translate objects with the matplotlib library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am fairly new to Python, and am currently working on a project that involves the 'matplotlib' library. Is it possible to create a polygon object, patch it to the defined points on the graph, and then translate that same exact polygon to another area on the graph, without creating a new polygon? This is my current code for generating and tiling a parallelogram:

```
for x in range(15):
    for y in range(10):
        parr = plt.Polygon(((x+1,y),(x,y),(x+1,y+1),(x+2,y+1)), fc = 'b', closed = True)
        plt.gca().add_patch(parr)
```

Rather than having it create new shapes along the axes, I would like to know if there is a way to take one shape and copy it to different positions.

Answer (score 0):

This would be what a `Collection` can be used for. You may create the `Polygon` once and supply it to a `PatchCollection`. Then define all the points where to place this polygon as `offsets`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as mcol
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
import numpy as np

poly = plt.Polygon(((1,0),(0,0),(1,1),(2,1)), fc = 'b', closed = True)
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(15), np.arange(10))
# create PatchCollection with all coordinates within x=(0..14), y=(0..9) as offsets
pcol = mcol.PatchCollection([poly,], offsets=np.c_[x.flatten(), y.flatten()], 
                            offset_position="data", transOffset=mtrans.IdentityTransform(), 
                            transform=plt.gca().transData)
# colorize the patches
pcol.set_array(np.random.rand(15*10))

plt.gca().add_collection(pcol)
plt.gca().set(xlim=(0,16),ylim=(0,10))       
plt.show()
```

[image]